# Append Rows to DataGrid on ButtonClick

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Datagrid that is supposed to be a list of SSH commands I run. For some reason it isn't appending to the list, it just replaces the content. Here is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="CommandRows2" Margin="0,0,0,87" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Delete" Binding="{Binding Delete}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Command" Binding="{Binding Command}" Width="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Response" Binding="{Binding Response}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test Results" Binding="{Binding Results}" Width="70"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is the code:

```
List<CommandGridItems> items = new List<CommandGridItems>();

private void ExecuteSingleCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string sshCommand = "hostname";
    string returnedResults = "localhost";
    items.Add(new CommandGridItems() { Delete = false, Command = sshCommand, Response = returnedResults, Results = "desc1" });
    CommandRows2.ItemsSource = items;
}

public class CommandGridItems
{
    public bool Delete { get; set; }
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public string Results { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing the `Items` list should do it.

```
CommandRows2.ItemsSource = items;
CommandRows2.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

when you set `CommandRows2.ItemsSource = items;` repeatedly, nothing happens on second and next assignments, because value (`items`) doesn't change, it is the same reference.

change `List<CommandGridItems> items = new List<CommandGridItems>();` to `ObservableCollection<CommandGridItems> items = new ObservableCollection<CommandGridItems>();` and simply add new elements without re-assigning ItemsSource:

```
private void ExecuteSingleCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string sshCommand = "hostname";
    string returnedResults = "localhost";
    var element = new CommandGridItems() { Delete = false, Command = sshCommand, Response = returnedResults, Results = "desc1" }
    items.Add(element);
}
```

A single added element will be shown in DataGrid because ObservableCollection notifies about elements changing via `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface event (`CollectionChanged`), while calling `Refresh` in this situation is a performance hit.

`INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` are "must do" in WPF for notifying UI about changes in a ViewModel